# How to change the pagination position

Tags: 8, theming, paging

I have created a custom block using Entity Query with pagination to get the data and everything works fine with

```
$render[] = [
  '#type' => 'pager',
];
```

But I can find a way to change the position of the pager. For example, I want to include them in my custom block template. I can't do that.

For Drupal 7 we have the following option but I can find the same way to do that in Drupal 8

```
theme('pager')
```

Thanks for your help